# C# How to use ISupportExternalScope with customer ILogger/ILoggerProvider and middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-middleware, ilogger

I have a custom ILogger / ILoggerProvider implementation that is basically a fancy JsonConsole logger to format things as required for our console log forwarding.

Everything works fine, including using ILogger.BeginScope to pass custom data to the log method(s).

Next, I am trying to write some middleware that looks at the HttpContext and automagically adds certain fields to the log scope.

What I have so far - I've trimmed out everthing not related to the log scope:

```
public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
    // ...

    private readonly string _categoryName;
    private IExternalScopeProvider _scopeProvider { get; set; }

    public MyLogger(string categoryName, IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider)
    {
        _categoryName = categoryName;
        _scopeProvider = scopeProvider;
    }

    // ...
}

public class MyLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    // ...

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return _loggers.GetOrAdd(categoryName, new MyLogger(
            categoryName,
            new LoggerExternalScopeProvider()
        ));
    }
    // ...
}

public static ILoggingBuilder AddMyLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder) 
{
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>());
    return builder;
}

// Program.cs

services.AddLogging(logBuilder => 
{
    logBuilder.ClearProviders();
    logBuilder.AddMyLogger();
});


// !!! Everything below here is conjecture - I don't have it working yet.

public class MyAutoLogScopeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyAutoLogScopeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider)
    {
        var logInfo = "Hi there!";
        
        using (scopeProvider.Push(logInfo))
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}

public static class MyAutoLogScopeMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyAutoLogScope(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyAutoLogScopeMiddleware>();
    }
}

// Program.cs

app.UseMyAutoLogScope();
```

My question is how do I get the IExternalScopeProvider into the provider via dependency injection instead of newing one up?

Should I be registering it as `.AddScoped<IExternalScopeProvider,LoggerExternalScopeProvider>()`, and then change the provider to `.AddScoped` as well?

I feel like I should be using `ISupportExternalScope.SetScopeProvider(IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider)` on MyLoggerProvider, but I can't find any examples of how to use that with dependency injection.

If anyone has a working example, I'd really appreciate a link to a blog post or article.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is _loggers declared?

Comment: @DavidThielen It is just a private object in the class that is used to ensure only a single logger is created per .categoryName.     `private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyLogger> _loggers = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: Is that an issue? I assumed the ILogger system would be smart enough to not ask for dups. TIA

Comment: I think that depends on how to configure your scope objects.  If you have a Singleton that asks for an `ILogger<MyService>` and nothing else asks for `ILogger<MyService>` then yes - I would only expect `CreateLogger` to be called once for that object.

But, if you have a Scoped lifetime or ask for `ILogger<MyService>` from multiple constructors then I'd expect `CreateLogger` to be called multiple times for MyService.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logger provider should implement `ISupportExternalScope` and pass along any scope provider to its loggers.

```
public class MyLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider, ISupportExternalScope
{
    private IExternalScopeProvider _externalScopeProvider;

    void ISupportExternalScope.SetScopeProvider(IExternalScopeProvider externalScopeProvider) =>
        _externalScopeProvider = externalScopeProvider

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return _loggers.GetOrAdd(categoryName, new MyLogger(
            categoryName,
            _externalScopeProvider
        ));
    }
}
```

The logger factory system will call `ISupportExternalScope.SetScopeProvider`. You don't need to do it, and you don't need to provide an `ISupportExternalScope` to the DI, either.

Your application code should not call `IExternalScopeProvider.Push` to create scopes; instead, use `ILogger.BeginScope`:

```
public class MyAutoLogScopeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<MyAutoLogScopeMiddleware> _logger;

    public MyAutoLogScopeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<MyAutoLogScopeMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var logInfo = "Hi there!";
        
        using (_logger.BeginScope(logInfo))
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```